# How to position SVG text element in a cross-browser and bidi-friendly manner?

Tags: css, svg, right-to-left

I want to position a string of text inside the bottom right corner of an `svg rect` element in both RTL and LTR languages. Unfortunately, IE obeys the `text-anchor` attribute strictly regardless of text direction, whereas Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera swap the meaning of 
`text-anchor: start` and `text-anchor: end` in RTL mode. How can I position the text correctly cross-browser and in an RTL-compatible manner?

LTR: http://jsfiddle.net/ybr1s4d4/ (correct)

RTL: http://jsfiddle.net/ybr1s4d4/2/ (doesn't work in IE9+, don't care about IE8-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define specific CSS rules for IE9 alone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364891/how-to-define-specific-css-rules-for-ie9-alone)

Comment: To add on the issue..., how would you do this in IE/Edge for something like?
<text x="300" y="10" stroke="none"" style="direction: rtl;">מאי - יוני 2016</text> where you have text in RTL then number (or number, then text if you look from left side)?

Answer (score -1):

For IE, you don't need any CSS rule (to re-define the `text-anchor`), so we can detect the IE browser and if it's not IE, just insert the rule (to override the `text-anchor`) using Javascript like this:

```
//if not IE, just insert the rule body[dir="rtl"] svg > text ...
if(!('ActiveXObject' in window)){
  document.styleSheets[0]
          .insertRule("body[dir='rtl'] svg > text { text-anchor: start;}",0);    
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ybr1s4d4/4/).

Note I think it's not possible to solve this without using script.

Comment: Without your added rule (meaning `ltr`), the text is not correctly placed.

Comment: @Elfayer you don't even understand the purpose of the question. That is to detect if the current browser is IE (so the most important thing in my answer is the `if` statement). There is not any constraint between the `ltr` or `rtl` with what you see on the UI which is determined by the CSS `text-anchor` (the default value is set in CSS section is `end` while the dynamic setting (which changes the value to `start`) is done via script and with the condition of the `if` statement. You should understand the question ***well*** before giving any wrong comment and downvote to the answerer.

Comment: I tried to remove it in fact, but SO is locking it until the post is edited =/