# Applying `css` internet explorer 9 specific css property affects ie10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I am writing a `ie9` specific `css` property. but it affets `ie10` too..

how to avoid this?

here is my property:

```
.back { visibility:visible; }

:root .back { visibility:hidden\0/IE9; }
```

i am viewing the result using the `ie` document mode.

Comment: I just googled `\0/IE9` and the [first result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364891/how-to-define-specific-css-rules-for-ie9-alone) pointed me to an [article](https://davidmurdoch.com/2011/05/13/ie9-only-css-hack/) that explains `\0/IE9` applies to IE10 as well. You need to work on your research/googling skills. Your best bet is conditional comments instead, see here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should target IE9 only (and not IE10 etc as `:root` does):

```
@media screen and (min-width:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
 // IE9 CSS
 .back{visibility:hidden;}
}
```